# How do I share an AES algorithm key between application and microservice

Tags: encryption, cryptography, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using an AES algorithm to encrypt a file and store on AWS.

I will then use a microservice to read this encrypted file from AWS, decrypt it and do some more processing on the file.

How do I share the AES key and IV between the application and microservice?

This is what I have so far for Encryption.  I used AES.Create() outside of this function and pass the algorithm into it with the steam I would like to encrypt.

```
 public async Task<Stream> Encrypt(Stream stream, SymmetricAlgorithm aes)
    {
        // TODO: How to share algorithm key between this app and microservice?
        aes.Key = GetKey();
        aes.IV = GetIv();

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {

                stream.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
            }

            return memoryStream;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How to share the key is quite central to the entire protocol. How to do *key management* is subject of books rather than papers. If the key needs to be refreshed depends on the protocol as well, but in general you should try and design for key change.

Keys can be stored in key containers, TPM's, SAM's, HSM, source code, configuration files etc. The trick is to store it in such a way that it is better protected than the messages it protects otherwise it doesn't make sense to use encryption in the first place. Keys can also be generated on the fly, e.g. by using a key agreement protocol such as Diffie-Hellman. For many applications asymmetric key management - for instance using certificates - makes a lot of sense.

The IV is a lot easier: it can simply be stored with the ciphertext. Often it is simply prefixed to it: the IV is often a static size, such as the key size.

---

Unfortunately your use cases, thread model and system are not specified, so giving full advice is impossible, *even if this would be the role of StackOverflow at all*.

Comment: Thanks for the response and thanks for the tip about key security and attaching the IV to the start of the ciphertext.